# ERROR : IP Adrress of the system using JAVA

Tags: java, sockets, ip

I used InetAddress for getting IP Address.

This is my code

```
String hostname=args[0];


        try {
            InetAddress ipaddress= InetAddress.getByName(hostname);
            System.out.println("IPADDRESS" +ipaddress.getHostAddress());
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            System.out.println("Could not find anything" +hostname);
        }
```

But in the console

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at com.networking.ipaddress.IP.main(IP.java:11)
```

What's the problem actually ? Problem with the code or system?

Comment: If with "args" you mean default program args:If you don't call the program with any arg "args" will be of size 0 amd [0] will be out of array. Use if (args.Length > 0) before access it.

Comment: are u passing the args value?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the host name from program arguments but you do not specify hostname as program argument while launching java so **args[] array is empty** array and that's why  accessing its [0] element throws exception.
You have to specify hostname as argument to the java while running your application as follows:

```
java YourClassFileName 192.168.1.1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the line 11 in your class for the exact place, but apparently it's the line you assign the hostname form args array.

```
String hostname=args[0];
```

If it's the args[] array of main method, make sure you pass the hostname when you run your program.